# How to Loop through a different Strings with different indexes and reverse their item[i] and item[i+1] every time?

Tags: python, loops

Here is my code:
I used python for this question.

```
import sys
import math

t = input()
lst = []
for i in range(0, len(t), 2):
    lst.append(t[i+1])
    lst.append(t[i])

answer = "".join(lst)
print(answer)
```

1. `Input 1 : 01ABxy  Output: 10BAyx`

However, my program only works with index with even numbers, when I try plug something like this:

2. `Input 2: ReadabilityCounts  Output: The index out of range.`

Comment: What is the desired behavior? Do you want the last character to just stay in place if there's an odd amount of items?

Comment: Yes, If there's an odd amount, just let the last character to stay in its place.

Answer (score 1):

check the parity of the length of your input and modify your code accordingly:

```
lst = []
for i in range(len(t)//2):
    lst.append(t[2*i+1])
    lst.append(t[2*i])
if len(t)%2:
    lst.append(t[-1])
answer = "".join(lst)
```

Comment: wow, okay, I've draw the output on the paper, I have to say, this is a really creative way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

My solutions if the length is odd:

```
import sys
import math

t = input()
lst = []
for i in range(0, len(t)-1, 2):
    lst.append(t[i+1])
    lst.append(t[i])
if len(t) %2 !=0:
    lst.append(t[-1])
answer = "".join(lst)
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can replace

```
lst.append(t[i+1])
lst.append(t[i])
```

With `lst.append(t[i:i+2][::-1])`
This prevents the error since `t[i:i+2]` will only take one element if the string is too small.

Comment: Sorry, I quite not understand the slice notation there, can you explain to me a little bit?

Comment: Oh sure, `t[i:i+2]` returns 2 elements starting at index i.
and `list[::-1]` is just the whole list but in reverse order (the -1 there is the step, and a step of -1 means going backwards by 1)  
if we combine those two we get the list of the two elements starting at index i in reverse order, exactly what we needed!
if t[i+1] doesn't exist we get a list of one element, reversing it doesn't do anything and we still get what we wanted.